# Is there charges for unfilled option

Tags: options

I failed to get filled on an option trade and was canceled. Will I be charge a fee still or only when an order is filled? Thanks.

Comment: I've never heard of a US/Canadian broker that charges fee's for orders that aren't filled, but perhaps that's customary in whatever country you are from.

Comment: Some brokers charge a fee if you cancel an open option order during regular trading hours, and some brokers charge a fee for *placing* an order if you do it by phone or with a live broker rather than online, but I've never heard of being charged extra for an option order that expires. Ask your broker.